# how to take more than 20 digit in phone number

Tags: java

I used `BigDecimal` for phone number but its not taking more than 20 digit. What do I have to use?

```
if(loginDTO.getPhoneNumber()!=null && loginDTO.getPhoneNumber().length()>0){
    userBO.setPhoneNo(new BigDecimal(loginDTO.getPhoneNumber()));
}
```

I want something in place of `BigDecimal` here which will takemore than 20 numbers.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is not the issue here. How do you save the phone number into `loginDTO`? Which type is it?

Comment: its String type actually we use webservice request there we send String type but again we set it to BigDecimal for saving to DB

Comment: String would just work fine.

Comment: You do realize that some phone numbers start with a 0 which cannot be reproduced using a numeric data format. You should use strings for phone numbers.

Comment: Thats why we took string but its not taking when we are giving more than 20 numbers in request

Comment: @smita There must be something wrong with how you save that number. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/fAws2X), it builds a 30 digit BigDecimal. BigDecimal can potentially hold as many digits as you want

Comment: Is the phone number a floating point value or why do you use `BigDecimal` instead of `BigInteger`?

Comment: I'm afraid `BigDecimal` isn't the cause of the problem here ([ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ckmZ3C)). Could you please provide more context to the question and specify what do you mean exactly with _is not taking_ ?

Answer (score 6):

You will not want to use any number format for a phone number at all. For example - I am living in Hamburg/Germany, so my local number would be `040-9999999` while `040` is my area code.

But alas, no leading zeroes in a decimal format.

Or international format: `+49-40-9999999` or having an extension: `+49-40-999999-99`.

Or simply wanting to format the numbers into groups for easy dialing (you may only want to do that for the display part, so that point is only semi valid):

```
+49 40-999 999 ext 99
```

As you never calculate anything with these numbers, save yourself the hassle. Take a string.

Comment: Adding to the above answer.I think also you should think of breaking up the phone numbers into various segment for ease of processing.

Comment: or people that have an extension like -99.

Comment: I hope the poor fellow with the number +49 40-999 999 does not get any prank calls after this.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not a good idea to store phone numbers as a numeric data type due to area code and country code formatting. Plus, storing them as a number doesn't buy you anything (how often do you perform math operations on a phone number)?

Try storing your phone numbers as a String.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to model the phone number in a `String` variable.

Interpreting a telephone number as a number can lead to issues with, for instance, telephone numbers starting with `0`, or managing country codes (`+01`). Plus, you'll get rid of the length issue.

Comment: I have imei_No which should take 40 upto digit but big decimal is not taking

Comment: Have you tried using `BigInteger`? See this [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ckmZ3C) for a 40-digit number. However, if you're not going to perform arithmetic operations on those numbers, I'd also suggest using `String` to manage them.

Comment: String we are using in request packet but for setting the value in business object we are using Big decimal so what can i able to use